# Change comman seperation to some other characters in multiple fields with same names values

Tags: html, asp-classic

I have a web form where there are multiple  are defined with same name generated via Classic asp code in a loop. When I receive the data when form is posted all the values are received in same variable with comma separated.

Now my question is whether it is possible to change the comma which work as a separation of different values with some other characters.

Comment: You can do it with JavaScript.

Comment: Sounds more like a design issue - why not attach a sequential number to the end of the ID/name?

Comment: Thanks paul, I have done what you have said attached a sequential no to the field name and then java script fetches the unique values depending on the field name

Answer (score 0):

```
dim yourField
yourField = Request.Form("yourFormField")
yourField = Replace(yourField ,",","#")
```

You obviously wouldn't be allowed commas in the value itself otherwise this would be deleted.

I'd maybe use JavaScript on the front end to replace all commas with something else and when you hit the ASP, after you've done the above, replace that 'something else' with a comma.

All depends what you intend to do with `yourField`

Comment: actually the field name are auto generated in the form and because of this names are common. What paul said is correct